# automatic call of retranslateUi

Tags: c++, qt

I have a base `myClass` class which inherits `QMainWindow`

```
class myClass : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    myClass(QWidget *par):QMainWindow(par);
    ~myClass(){};
}
```

and a bunch of subclasses which inherits from and are private members of their corresponding ui *e.g.*:

```
#include "ui_myPluginUi.h"
class myPlugin : public myClass, private Ui::myPluginUi {
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    Q_INVOKABLE myPlugin(QWidget *par): myClass(par), ;
    ~myPlugin(){};
}
```

So that I cas access my Ui widget easily.

My base class `myClass` has a lot of methods that load/save window preferences, do some connection on special widgets, decorate windows, load help pages for that window etc...

Most of them uses the wonderful retrospection of the qt-metasystem. One thing that I didn't succeed if to call `retranslateUi` from the base class.

I started reimplementing the `changeEvent`:

```
void myClass::changeEvent(QEvent *e)
{
    QWidget::changeEvent(e);
    switch (e->type()) {
    case QEvent::LanguageChange:
        for(int i =  0; i < metaObject()->methodCount(); ++i)
            qDebug() << i << metaObject()->method(i).methodSignature();
        break;
    default:
        break;
   }
}
```

but `retranslateUi` is not part of the methods...

I've seen that the UI class which implements `retranslateUi` is not a `QObject` and `retranslateUi` is not a `public slot` so I doubt there is a way unless there is a super-magical-qt-guru-move to do.

---

### Edited after @Kevin-Kremmer answer below:

If I add

```
private slots:
    virtual void retranslateUi(QMainWindow*) = 0;
```

I get a couple of errors `error: allocating an object of abstract class type 'myClass'` since I'm also able to create pure `MyClass` objects and decorate them via plain ui file via `QUiLoader` ...

and if I define a

```
private slots:
    virtual void retranslateUi(QMainWindow*) {};
```

that is the only one that the metasystem sees and calls...

(hope to be clear enough)

Comment: Can you add a public slot e.g. retranslateUiSlot() to your QObject, that simply calls retranslateUi() ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
// in myClass
private slots:
    virtual void retranslateUi(QMainWindow*) = 0;
```

Comment: not bad, but it doesn't suit my needs because (forgot to mention...) some derived class are pure `myClass` and I get `error: allocating an object of abstract class type 'myClass'`  (I've edited the question) thanks a lot for the effort It was quite close!

Comment: Maybe you only need another base class then. Classes which also inherit from a "Ui" class get the virtual implemented by that.

For the classes that derive from myClass but use a QUiLoader, create a new intermediary, i..e. that derives from myClass, has a QUiLoader member and implements retranslateUi() appropriately.